# How to stop looping to get only the contents of first array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, for-loop

This is the mockup of my code.

I'm receiving a data in this variable:

```
this.data = data.details;
```

and then I'm filtering for duplicates to be removed and put in another array like this:

```
let dataUnique = this.data.filter(function(el, index, self) {
     return index == self.indexOf(el);
}
```

The `console.log` of `dataUnique`:

```
Array[14]
0: "a"
1: "b"
2: "c"
3: "d"
4: "e"
5: "g"
6: "h"
7: "i"
8: "j"
9: "k"
10: "l"
11: "m"
12: "n"
13: "o"
```

Now the issue happens here in this if statement:

```
if(something == true) {
        let uData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        switch (uData.language) {
             case 'de':
             document.querySelector('table tr').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<td'> + dataUnique + '</td>');
             break;
        }
    }
```

The issue is that I'm getting the amount of `tds` with `dataUnique array` fields which equals to the number of `something` is `true` in my `if` statement before the `switch`.

So instead of getting:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
    </td>
</table>
```

I'm receiving:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
        <td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>
    </td>
</table>
```

The amount of `<td>a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o</td>` equals to the number `something == true` in my `if` statement. I know what the issue is, but I do not know how to solve it.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have for in loop above, ie:

```
for (let sth in somethingObj) {
     let something = somethingObj[sth];
     if(something.something == true) {...}
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a loop inside which you have your if ? post a [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code please ..

Comment: Please note that I can 'solve' it with CSS: table td:not(:first-child){display:none;}, but that isn't really a soluton.

Comment: I have it above, give me a sec.

Comment: There you go, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript allows you to name loops (as defined in EMCA-262 section 12.12. [[MDN Docs]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)).

This lets us specify the loop name to the `break` command so that js breaks out of THAT loop:

```
loop1:
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
loop2:
  for(var j=0;j<10;j++) {

    console.log(i, j);
    break loop1;

  }
}
```

Here we are telling the break command to break out of `loop1`. The result, in `console.log` is `0 0`. If we had just the break, we would end up with something like:

```
0 0
1 0
2 0
3 0
4 0
5 0
6 0
7 0
8 0
9 0
```

Feeding this logic into your code:

```
outerLoop:
for (let sth in somethingObj) {
     let something = somethingObj[sth];
     if(something == true) {
        let uData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        switch (uData.language) {
             case 'de':
             document.querySelector('table tr').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<td'> + dataUnique + '</td>');
             break outerLoop;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Putting the check inside the loop of course gives you as many `td`s as many as the `true`s , the `break` you have is inside the `switch` and hence is only valid for the `switch` and not for the `for` loop... I'd say evaluate the `something.something` and assign it to a variable and then do the next step :

```
var test = false;
for (let sth in somethingObj) {
     let something = somethingObj[sth];
     if(something.something == true) {test=true;break ;}
}
if(test){//do your if business here.
let uData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    switch (uData.language) {
         case 'de':
         document.querySelector('table tr').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<td'> + dataUnique + '</td>');
         break;
    }
}
```

Another way (with minimal edits to your logic) :

```
for (let sth in somethingObj) {
     let something = somethingObj[sth];
     if(something.something == true) {
        let uData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
    switch (uData.language) {
         case 'de':
         document.querySelector('table tr').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<td'> + dataUnique + '</td>');
         break; // this breaks out of the switch ..
    } break; // this breaks out of the for loop
     }
}
```

Comment: Please give me a sec.

Comment: Could you please apply this on my full code, I'm missing something here..

Comment: No you have a break in the switch ... You need it out of the switch ... Check my edit please.

Comment: Second way helped narrow to only 5 tds... (I had 20 of them). I have another for in loop above the one, could that be the issue?

Comment: @eric.dummy Yes

Comment: Then I think you should use the first way ... out of the nested `for` loops .. take a boolean `var sthFound=false`... and set it to true if you ever get a `something.something == true` and after the loops .. just check `if(sthFound) { // Parse JSON and add the td as you wish`

Comment: Still nothing.. Wait please. Thanks :)

Comment: You know now how to reduce and jump out of the for loop ... rest I'd suggest you try out yourself before ordering more SO Service on the Platter

Comment: This si done, naming the loop helped. Thank you for assistance, too. :) Cheers!